# Client certificates with AWS API Gateway

Tags: authentication, ssl, https, client-certificates, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to implement mutual authentication for the communication between aws api gateway and my server.  I want to use the client side certificates that amazon offers for authentication.  I know that my server is configured correctly because previously I was using a lambda function and mutual authentication was working.

I have exported the (.PEM) certificate and added it into a truststore.  I have configured my Jetty server to use that truststore for authentication.  I have set client-auth to :need.  I know my server is set up correctly because it was working with with my self-implemented mutual SSL.  All I did was change the truststore.  When I test my method gateway returns a 200:
 { "message": "Unknown endpoint error."}

Here is an excerpt from the server log files.  It appears that the server side handshake completes, but there is an error with the client certificate.

> pConnection@3a0a2e84{FILLING} server-side handshake completed
>   2015-09-28 13:04:29,856 DEBUG [qtp1980278840-19]
>   o.e.j.i.ChannelEndPoint - flushed 45
>   SelectChannelEndPoint@2c05eeb2{ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com/5x.xxx.xxx.x:43942<->4000,Open,in,out,-,-,0/200000,SslConnection}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1}
>   2015-09-28 13:04:29,856 DEBUG [qtp1980278840-19]
>   o.e.j.i.s.SslConnection -
>   SslConnection@50e2de43{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=0/0,di=-1} ->
>   HttpConnection@3a0a2e84{FILLING} flush exit, consumed 0 2015-09-28
>   13:04:29,856 DEBUG [qtp1980278840-19] o.e.j.i.s.SslConnection -
>   SslConnection@50e2de43{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=0/-1,di=-1} ->
>   HttpConnection@3a0a2e84{FILLING} unwrap Status = BUFFER_UNDERFLOW
>   HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved this problem.  The server logs I posted are misleading.  No handshake occurs because the server certificate I was using was self signed, not signed by a trusted CA.  As of 9/28/2015, aws api gateway requires a certificate signed by a trusted certificate authority.  Because my cert was self signed, the server (and client) handshakes do not complete.  Hopefully this problem will be solved in future versions.

Comment: For others, setting up client cert authentication between the API gateway and server is covered in the docs here.. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html