# Howto install the api gateway client certificate into Elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, client-certificates, aws-api-gateway

I have a scalable application on elastic beanstalk running on Tomcat. I read that in front of Tomcat there is an Apache server for reverse proxy. I guess I have to install on apache the client certificate and configure it to accept only request encrypted by this certificate, but I have no idea how to do that.

Can you help me?

Comment: EBS = Elastic Block Store

Comment: Sorry, Elastic Beanstalk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many researches I found a solution. According to the difficult to discover it I want share with you my experience.

My platform on elastic beanstalk is Tomcat 8 with load balancer.

To use the client certificate (at the moment I was writing) you have to terminate the https on instance

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance.html

then

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-tomcat.html

I used this configuration to use both client and server certificates (seems that it doesn't work only with client certificate)

```
    SSLEngine             on
    SSLCertificateFile    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/GandiStandardSSLCA2.pem"
    SSLCipherSuite        EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
    SSLProtocol           All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLHonorCipherOrder   On
    SSLVerifyClient       require
    SSLVerifyDepth        1
    SSLCACertificateFile  "/etc/pki/tls/certs/client.crt"
```

And last thing: api gateway doesn't work with self signed cerificate (thanks to [Client certificates with AWS API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828670/client-certificates-with-aws-api-gateway)), so you have to buy one from a CA.

```
SSLCACertificateFile  "/etc/pki/tls/certs/client.crt"
```

This is where you should point the API Gateway provided client side certificate.

Comment: I have similar problem: I want to restrict access to my EB that only API Gateway can talk with it. I use NGINX and multidocker configuration on EB. What server.crt and server.key have you used? As you mentioned in last sentence, you bought SSL Certificate from trusted external provider (like GoDaddy). am I right?

Comment: Yes I bought It from strarfield

Comment: @eGO In your EB, behind ELB, you run many instances, am I right?

Comment: And probably last question: You generated SSL server certificate for specific domain (or subdomain or wildcard domain/subdomain). Do you bind this domain to Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: We have a wildcard certificate because we use the same certificate for more environments on Elastic beanstalk (dev, qa, prod). On route53 I bound the every subdomain to each environments on eb

Comment: Great, thanks for the answers, you probably saves me a lot time on researches!

Comment: @nicq ehere you able to accomplish this? I have the exact same configuration than you and am trying to setup the client certificates in my Beanstalk environment but I haven't accomplished it yet. Can you share how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Not yet, I think in this week I'll be able to finish that. I wait for SSL cert and subdomains from my admin. I'll post the answer with details after all.

Comment: @aGO : I believe here you have added the Client side certificate provided by the API Gateway, the answer does not clearly defines where the certificate is used, after your response I will update the answer `SSLCACertificateFile  "/etc/pki/tls/certs/client.crt"`

Comment: @aGO :  have you added this configuration in ssl.conf file by uploading folder .ebextensions/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf or there is an easier way to add client certificate from aws console? I am using reference of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-proxy.html#java-tomcat-proxy-apache

Comment: I added the configuration to the .ebextensions folder. At the time of the post, I didn't know another way to accomplish it

Answer (score 1):

You might have to configure the ELB's listener for vanilla TCP on the same port instead of HTTPS. Basically TCP pass through at your ELB, your instance needs to handle on the SSL in order to authorize the requests which provided a valid client certificate.

Comment: what does vanilla TCP mean?